How to Run Compiled MATLAB Executable Without MATLAB Installed?
I use mcc -m main.m to create an exe file.  When I run it on another computer that does not have Matlab installed, I get this error
Could not find version 24.1 of the MATLAB Runtime. Attempting to load mclmcrrt24_1.dll. Please install the correct version of the MATLAB Runtime. Contact your vendor if you do not have an installer for the MATLAB Runtime.

I asked GPT, and it suggested I use mcc -m main.m -R -logfile But it doesn't work.
I want the exe file to run on a computer that did not have Matlab installed or MATLAB Runtime. How can I do that?

The error message is pretty clear about the solution: “Please install the correct version of the MATLAB Runtime.” The documentation for MATLAB Compiler is also pretty clear: “End users can run your applications royalty-free using MATLAB Runtime.” See here for more information on the runtime: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/matlab-runtime.html

You can't. Not unless you have a Matlab coder license and generate C code from which you can actually compile a stand alone executable. You can redistribute the Matlab runtime with your current application: https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html. Check the licenses to make sure they fit your use case.
